# Set of points and determine them based on occurrence

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I get set of points from a frame of video. For every frame in the video I get set of points. I would like to list the points based on the frequency of occurrence. Please suggest me the best way to do so like training a network or building it a statistical way.

Comment: maybe you should simply create dictionary with `point: count_number` and use standard `collections.Counter` for this. It doesn't need extra modules.

Comment: @furas Thank you, we have tried that statistical way of modelling. But is there any way that i can train a network which can define the occurrences??